# Installing OAuth on WampServer x86 with php 5.4.3?

Tags: php, oauth, wampserver

I'm trying to install OAuth on WampServer x86 with php 5.4.3 and have tried adding extensions from pierre, even tried installing directly from PECL. These have all produced errors in the logs, and haven't enabled OAuth. Does anyone know which dll version I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

The only dll I found to work for that version is from the windows.php.net directory: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/php_oauth-1.2.3-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip

Best of luck to anyone who has to deal with this on another version...

Comment: +1 Actually, I was searching for the php_apc.dll for XP. http://windows.php.net really helped.